# WinForms: When ObjectForScripting is set, HTML is not displayed

Tags: c#, html, winforms, object

I have a Windows forms application and a separate HTML page. The two are supposed to communicate with each other. I followed the instructions from [this microsoft link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Before I set the ObjectForScripting with `WebBrowser.ObjectForScripting = this;`, the HTML page displayed correctly. However, after setting `ObjectForScripting`, the HTML will not display in the WebBrowser component whatsoever. It gives the error "window.external is null or not an object."

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FirstCSharpApp
{
    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser.AllowWebBrowserDrop = false;
            WebBrowser.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;
            WebBrowser.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = false;
            WebBrowser.ObjectForScripting = this;

            string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            WebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/Timeline.html", curDir)));
        }

        private void GoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Works!
            WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("test",
                new String[] { "called from client code" });
        }

        private void homeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser.GoHome();
        }

        private void goBackToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            WebBrowser.GoBack();
        }

        private void goForwardToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser.GoForward();
        }

        public void Test(String message)
        {
            // Does not work, or apparently even exist
            MessageBox.Show(message, "client code");
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function test(message) {
            alert(message);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick ="window.external.Test('called from script')">
        Call client code.
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You really should include YOUR code, just in case there was a copy paste mistake. It is one of the most common errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing these attributes on your form class.

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
```

> You can set this property to any COM-visible object for which you want
>   its public properties and methods available to scripting code. You can
>   make a class COM-visible by marking it with the `ComVisibleAttribute`.

Comment: From my understanding on the docs, if it is `public` it will already be tagged as Com Visible. I tagged it anyway, and it did not fix my problem.